# How to open .doc or .docx extension file using robot framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have to open downloaded .doc or .docx file using robot framework from my windows machine. If any of you have ever worked on opening external files using robot framework, I request your knowledge.

Comment: you want to read contents of the file?

Comment: What do you mean by "open"? Do you literally mean to open the file for reading and/or writing (with the python `open`) statement, or do you mean you want microsoft word to start up and load the file?

Answer (score 1):

Using the keyword [Run](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Run) (or it's siblings) from the [OperatingSystem](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html) Library should do the trick. In the below example I've put the test.docx file next to the robot script.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    OperatingSystem    

*** Test Cases ***
Open Word
    Run    C:\\PROGRA~2\\MICROS~2\\Office14\\winword.exe ${EXECDIR}${/}test.docx
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: If this is the answer you're looking for, please mark it as answered so that others know this is the solution that worked for you.